# Hacer un filtro con los datos que tiene la columna

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-admin, django-suit

Intento hacer un filtro con los datos que tiene esta columna:

```
def show_manager(self, obj):
    if obj.puesto and not isinstance(obj.puesto, Individual) and obj.puesto.manager \
            or isinstance(obj.puesto, Fondo):
        return obj.puesto.manager
    return ''
```

No sé muy bien cómo debería hacer el filtro con los datos que tiene la columna

```
class ManagerFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Manager'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return self.value()

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
        #  No sé que poner
        else:
             return ''
```

Muchas gracias anticipadamente

Comment: Buen día, ¿Columna de qué? ¿Qué datos deseas filtrar? ¿Cuál es la salida esperada? ¿Cuáles son los datos de entrada?. Saludos :)

Comment: Los datos que tenga en la BD la columna show_manager.
Como no son datos concretos sino datos que se van añadiendo....